# posts_per_page not working beyond 375 limit

Tags: php, wordpress

my query doesn't seem to want to function if the post limit set is beyond what it is... i.e. if I have 370 rows of information and I set the posts_per_page to anything beyond that, it won't run the query?!

```
wp_reset_query();

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        'posts_per_page' => 370,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I've tried using 1000, -1, all sorts, but it only functions if I enter the exact number of rows expected, otherwise the script fails to run at the WP_Query stage so don't have any errors either.

Edit: The actual limit seems to be at 375, after that, nothing executes although there are 386 actual rows that fulfil the criteria.

Any ideas?!!

Comment: try to add 'showpost' => -1

Comment: This only returns 10 rows unfortunately

Comment: try to delete 'posts_per_page' => 370 and add 'showpost' => -1

Comment: Have you tried setting `nopaging` as described here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters?

Comment: Yes, tried that AndrePliz :( I thought that might have been the answer the CBroe but still no joy unfortunately - seems to completely flop at anything over 375 and don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'posts_per_page' => 370,
    );
    query_posts($args);

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php echo the_content(); ?>


<?php 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Same issue hitting 375 unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

This MUST work

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'courses',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if($the_query->have_posts()) : 
        while($the_query->have_posts()) : 
         $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    YOUR HTML CODE
<?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
```

Comment: I've tried exactly that and no joy. There must be something else somewhere limiting this?!

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem except the limit for my CTP was 411.  Anymore more rows and the query didn't work. Came across a few similar posts and one solution was to increase server resources but then I looked for how to improve wp_query performance.  Try this:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'courses',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish', 
'update_post_term_cache' => false, // don't retrieve post terms
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, // don't retrieve post meta
);
```

It worked for me and seems a good option when displaying a CTP index listing page.  Discussed here:

https://drujoopress.wordpress.com/2013/06/27/how-to-optimize-wordpress-query-to-get-results-faster/#more-184

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Caching_Parameters